# Azure DevOps PRs reset approvals even when commits make no changes

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

Sometimes we have multiple active pull requests for a single project and naturally, they get approved and merged in turn. The problem we have is that when we make the first merge, we then merge the new master back into our other feature branch(es) and this process clears our existing votes/approvals on the PR(s) even if there are no merge conflicts and it's driving us insane!

We only recently started using Azure DevOps to manage our repositories and before that we used BitBucket, which identified that the merge had no additional code changes and didn't clear our votes. Azure DevOps knows that the commit doesn't add any new changes for the merge, but it still resets our votes.

[image]

**We do want our votes to reset when actual changes are made**, but is there a way to prevent vote resets in Azure DevOps in the special situation that the destination branch is merged back into the source branch, or if there is ever a commit that adds no changes to the PR?

Thanks guys!